# Find the voltage and the current of the circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, mesh-analysis

Can you help me to check if the results of the following circuit are right?

The exercise asks:
find the \$V_{3}(t)\$ and \$I_{3}(t)\$ having \$V_{2}(t)= \cos(2t + 165^\circ)\$ and \$I_{5}(t)=2\sin(2t -30^\circ)\$

My results are:
\$I_{3}(t) = 0.3425\cos(2t + 162^\circ)\$ \$V_{3}(t) = 1.0274\cos(2t + 162^\circ)\$

[image]

The voltage source on the left is \$V_{2}(t)\$

Here is my attempt:

Mesh method:

[image]

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
1-\frac{3}{4}J&\frac{J}{2}
\\\\
\frac{J}{2}&3-\frac{J}{2}
\\\\
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
I_1
\\\\
I_2
\\\\
\end{matrix}\right]
=
\left[\begin{matrix}
-0.433+0.25J
\\\\
-0.966+0.2588J
\\\\
\end{matrix}\right]$$

This solves to:

$$I_{1}=-0.44157+0.0818J$$

$$I_{2}=-0.326+0.1055J$$

So \$I_{3}(t) = 0.3425\cos(2t + 162^\circ)\$ and \$V_{3}(t) = 1.0274\cos(2t + 162^\circ)\$

Comment: Why not use a circuit simulator to check your result? They can be obscenely accurate for circuits like this. They are also free.

Comment: Can you link the site?

Comment: I use [micro-cap](https://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm) download link: https://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip

Comment: I'm having trouble to measure the current and the voltage with the software can you do it for me?

Comment: My recommendation is that you try and resolve the sim software yourself. But, you could also post the sim schematic into your question as a formal edit. Micro-cap (like LTspice) is a very powerful tool and, I encourage anyone thinking of EE as a job to learn it. I use it for everything because it catches problems and double checks my thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results are the following:

\$V_3(t) = 1.028 \cos(2t + 162°)\$

\$I_3(t) =  0.343 \cos(2t + 162°)\$